# Creating a random number by using SecureRandom and BigInteger

Tags: java, range, biginteger

Basically I have generated a random 1024 bits number by using randNo = BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, r). However, now I want to use the BitInteger randNo to create another random number which will have randNo has the maximum value and 2 as my minimum value i.e random number from 2 to randNo.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Not sure if some sort of conversion to bytes is required to pass to securerandom.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: You want to produce a random value between 1 and 1024 bits in length? Why not `BigInteger.probablePrime(512, r)`?

Comment: Thank you Elliot. However, although that solution would work, I still want the random value to be between 2 and up to the random 128 bit number. For example, if 8 bits generated 157, I would like the range to be from 2-157. Rather than just creating a 4 bit (8/2) random number. Thanks!

Comment: 1024 bit number (128 bytes, not bits). And I don't think you can, but good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one creative way I thought of to do it

```
BigInteger nextRandNo = new BigInteger(randNo).minus(BigInteger.valueOf(2L));
for(int i = 0; i < randNo.bitLength(); i++)
{
    if(r.nextBoolean())
        nextRandNo = nextRandNo.flipBip(i);
}
nextRandNo = nextRandNo.plus(BigInteger.valueOf(2L));
```

it might not be the fastest thing in the world but it will ensure every bit gets a bit of entropy and it should give you a BigInteger between 2 and your BigInteger value :)